# Keep ASP.NET site running without session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website that constantly scans a folder for files and then performs some actions on them. I dropped several thousand of these files into the directory, it started chugging but when I came back in the morning there were still files there. When I opened up a new session it started working again. Is it possible to keep this function running without a user having a session open?

Comment: I don't think this is a job for a Website. Windows service or a scheduled task sounds better here.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter that's simply not an option. This is a huge, preexisting product.

Comment: Perhaps increase session timeout in web.config or check the application pool, I think there's an option to never recycle the app pool.

Comment: Other things can reset session, too many variables here to be viable

Comment: Use a javascript page refresh? As previously mentioned, this is a task better done with a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in IIS, remove the session expiration time on both the website and the application pool. This means that once you fire/lookup the site once, it never shuts down. But as @Yuriy mentioned, what you're doing shouldn't be done via a website... get the information/perform your tasks using a windows service, and if need be, implement a way to display the tasks that were done in a website. But the web site shouldn't be doing the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 0):

Session is user-specific.If you do not want session state enabled for your application, you can set the session mode to Off. please refer this [msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/index.html).  It is a scheduler that will run tasks for you.